# Display the div in the table format when data is in column format

Tags: html, css

```
Col-1 col-2 col-3
A     AA     AA1
B     BB     BB1       
C     CC     CC1
```

I am want result like this.
But i am getting the data in the column format

please help how to handle this by CSS

```
<div class="name">A</div>
<div class="name">B</div>
<div class="name">C</div>
<div class="id">AA</div>
<div class="name">A</div>
<div class="name">B</div>
<div class="name">C</div>
<div class="id">AA</div>
<div class="id">BB</div>
<div class="id">CC</div>
<div class="val">AA1</div>
<div class="val">BB1</div>
<div class="val">CC1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use same no. of elements in each column, then this will help.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="name">A</div>
    <div class="name">B</div>
    <div class="name">C</div>

    <div class="id">AA</div>
    <div class="id">BB</div>
    <div class="id">CC</div>

    <div class="val">AA1</div>
    <div class="val">BB1</div>
    <div class="val">CC1</div>
</div>


.wrapper{
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aq0omnkL/